# Unity build for arm64

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, arm64, nvidia-jetson-nano

Im developing a 3d model which is to be deployed in a AARCH64 bit processor. I reffered how to build the unity exe for linux, and the linux build was success but under the linux im not be able to select the target architectures.(aarch64, arm64)
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/linux-IL2CPPcrosscompiler.html

I need to build my unity project for AARCH64 ,I had already tried installing toolchain packagaes, LL2CPP and also changed the scripting backend to the LL2CPP, but when im tried changing the scripting backend in **playersettings>othersetings>scriptingBackend** underthat there is target architecture but it was not listing any aarch64 or arm64 processors. im using unity editor 2021.3.29f1

Comment: I'm not 100% on the following information, so take it with a grain of salt. As far as I know there is no cross compiler for different chip architectures so the only "real" way to compile would be to install Unity on a Raspberry PI and compile your project natively. I haven't tried it myself, but the articles I read reported success (at the cost of inconvenience). I would also suggest if possible/appropriate to try to implement your project as a WebGL. All platforms, all architectures, no problems.

Comment: I thought targets were at build target level as a whole

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Unity supports Linux ARM64 only in the [Embedded Linux build version](https://docs.unity.com/embeddedlinux/en/manual/Installation) which requires [Unity Premium Runtimes](https://docs.unity.com/#Premium%20Runtimes)

Source:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-arm-64-linux-build-support.1366353/